# Good resource for in-depth study of Haftorah?

Tags: torah-study, product-recommendation, haftarah

Is there a good source for in-depth study of the weekly haftorah? I'm thinking of things like historical references, explanations of prophecies, etc.

Online or print would work.

Something that will give some background to the Haftorah.

Comment: Are you interested in commentaries on the passage used as the _haftara_ (i.e. commentaries on _Navi_) or in commentaries on the choice of _haftara_ (e.g. connections to the _parasha_)? Or both?

Comment: @msh210: both. If I wanted to learn the Haftorah on its own, without having to read the rest of the sefer for context, that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: +1 I find Haftarot are a very under-utilized resource by givers of Shabbat Divrei Torah.

Comment: Note, though, that out-of-context studies of random sections of Neviim is no replacement for actually learning the books that God thought it was worth recording for future generations.

Comment: [Haftorah Of The Week by Ervin Landau](https://www.amazon.com/Haftorah-Week-Overview-Elucidation-Prophets/dp/9655241688)

Comment: [הפטרה לעניין by Gadi Eidelheit](https://www.haftara.co.il/) and https://www.haftara.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94-150.pdf

Comment: [Kol Dodi by R' David Feinstein](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422614747.html)

Comment: [חזון המקרא -
הרב יששכר יעקבסון](https://www.hamadaf-y.co.il/%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%A0%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%97%D7%96%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%9A/)

Comment: [עין צופים - קושלבסקי](https://hebrewbooks.org/34407) [part 2](https://hebrewbooks.org/34409) [part 3](https://hebrewbooks.org/34408)

Comment: [Midrash Says Weekly Haftaros](https://www.amazon.com/Midrash-Says-Weekly-Haftaros-Vol/dp/B0013FY2H8)

Comment: [Haftorah Unrolled - Kira Sirote](https://www.gefenpublishing.com/product.asp?productid=2323)

Comment: [Haftara Handbook -  Jonathan Shooter](https://www.amazon.com/Haftara-Handbook-Lessons-Prophets-Contemporary/dp/1936068052)

Comment: [כוכב מיעקב](https://hebrewbooks.org/64555)

Comment: [Haftarah Helper - Kornblau and Beer](https://outorah.org/series/4081/)

Comment: [Birkat Hayim - R. Yossef Hayim](http://www.wslibrary.net/sifria/en/nach/7527--.html)

Comment: [הפטרות מבוארות חזון דוד](https://www.nehora.com/haftoras-chazon-dovid/)

Comment: [Hirsch Haftaros](https://www.judaicapress.com/products/hirsch-haftaros)

Comment: [The Haphtara Cycle - Stephen Rosenberg](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Haphtara_Cycle.html?id=HF_dMGP82moC&source=kp_book_description)

Comment: [The Haftarah Commentary - CCAR](https://www.ccarpress.org/shopping_product_detail.asp?pid=50298) (?)

Comment: [הפטרה וגמרא Yisrael Lerner](https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH990017376750205171/NLI)

Comment: [The Women's Haftarah Commentary](https://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/the-womens-haftarah-commentary-elyse-goldstein/1112023244)

Comment: [בן פרת יוסף](https://hebrewbooks.org/5656)

Comment: [מפטירין בנביא by אהרן אלדר](https://www.bialik-publishing.co.il/index.php?dir=site&page=catalog&op=item&cs=5642)

Comment: [הפטרת השבוע - רעיונות חינוכיים
 by ר רחמים מלמד כהן](https://www.aron-hasfarim.co.il/product.asp?productid=1801)

Comment: [הפטרה מפורשת by אליעזר לוי](https://biu.primo.exlibrisgroup.com/discovery/fulldisplay?docid=alma990005851940205776&context=L&vid=972BIU_INST:972BIU&lang=en&adaptor=Local%20Search%20Engine&tab=LibraryCatalog&query=sub%2Cexact%2CJewish%20ethics%2CAND&mode=advanced)

Comment: [משך הפרשה](https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH990023496520205171/NLI)

Comment: [*Educating a People* - Gidon Rothstein](https://www.lookstein.org/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/haftarot_book.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

This is what I've found so far:

- [Torah.org Haftorah by Rabbi Dovid Siegel](http://www.torah.org/learning/haftorah/). The Rabbi:

  - presents a general overview of the Haftorah together with historic background
  - isolates a hidden theme of the Haftorah
  - Finds a common thread which runs through the haftorah and the weekly Torah portion.
  - uses commentaries and midrashic sources to reveals ethic and moral lessons contained within the Haftorah.
- [Haftorahman](http://www.haftorahman.com/), by Reuben Ebrahimoff

  - a weekly newsletter devoted entirely to the weekly Haftorah. It is designed specifically to focus on the personalities and events found in the Navi (The Book of the Prophets).
- [Re-counting the Prophets](http://www.ou.org/torah/frankel/haftarot/), by Rabbi Pinchas Frankel
- Between the Fish and the Soup, by Jacob Soloman

  - This appears to be a multi-year series on the Haftorah, with [archives dating back to 5764](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/solomon/haftara/archives/archives64.htm)
- [Rabbi Berel Wein audio series](http://www.gotjudaica.com/Product.asp?product=ART-DS303)

  - an expensive series that goes through all the haftorot.
  - From the description: *Listen as Rabbi Berel Wein illuminates each haftorah's message for our times. His insights into the religious and historical background of every haftorah, and its connection to the Torah portion of the week, might even keep you awake after the Torah is put away!*

Answer (score 2):

R [Mosheh Lichtenstein](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%98%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9F) has a nice series on the weekly Haftorah available on the VBM [here](http://www.vbm-torah.org/haftara.html).

I see they also have a second (incomplete) series by R Yehuda Shaviv [here](http://www.vbm-torah.org/haftora.html), though I haven't read any of them.

Comment: R' Shaviv's series doesn't cover every parsha, but it pretty much covers the whole year, with just a few weeks missing.

Comment: R Mosheh's articles have now been worked into a book https://www.korenpub.com/toby_en_usd/maggid/book-categories/netivey-hanevua.html

Comment: R Shaviv's articles have now been worked into a book https://www.booknet.co.il/%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%94-7300008613