# Is there a volume in English that explicates the relationship between each haftarah and its parsha?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, haftarah, parsha-torah-portion

Is there a volume in English that explicates the relationship between each haftarah and its parsha?

Failing that, is there series of commentaries on the portions that routinely includes discussion of the haftarah?

Comment: very related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30037/759

Comment: @DoubleAA thank you for that. The different spelling was why my search hadn't found that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Kol Dodi on the Haftaros](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422614747.html), by [Rabbi David Feinstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovid_Feinstein).

According to the publisher:

> In this masterpiece, the Rosh Yeshivah introduces each Haftarah, explains its historical context where necessary, shows its relationship to the Parashah, and offers an enlightening commentary in his own unique, original manner.

Answer (score 2):

I think the Hertz Chumash does a good job.

Keep in mind, though, that not every Haftarah has a direct relationship to the Torah parsha or even a special occasion occurring on that day. For example, the 7 Haftarat of "Consolation" that occur between the week after Tish'a B'Av (Shabbat *Nachamu*) and prior to Rosh Hashanna (Netzavim or Netzavim / Vayelech) are mot directly related to the parsha reading.

Comment: I've now got this book. The commentary to each Haftarah starts with a paragraph or so of introduction. If there's deep link between the parsha and the haftarah, it gets explained at the start, whereas if the relationship is just tangential then there's merely a note at the end of the introduction. Which is helpful, thank you.

Comment: @chrysanthemum I greatly appreciate your comment and I'm glad this helped you. There are so many resources around. My shul has stuck with Hertz for years, perhaps, b/c it is an 87 year old shul and Conservative / Traditional. They proposed using Art Scroll as that's the current trend, but congregants resisted. I'm glad they did. I think Hertz offers educated views from other sources that inspire a bit more critical thinking than Art Scroll does. In a sense, Art Scroll spoon feeds you on how you SHOULD think, IMO. I hope you enjoy Hertz.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite is the commentary of R' Samson Raphael Hirsch on the haphtaros, he often connects the two.

In addition, the classic Stone Chumash from ArtScroll has a note on every haphtorah, often explaining the non-obvious connections.

Comment: That commentary isn't by RSRH himself, but by one of his sons.

Comment: @Shamiach useful to know thanks. So he authored vol.6 in that blue edition, and the other 5 were his father's?

Comment: Yes. The son's name, btw, was R' Mendel Hirsch.

Answer (score 1):

The Samson Raphael Hirsch chumash set has a volume dedicated to the haftorah, many times explaining the connecting theme.

In Hebrew, there is Rabbi Shimon Schwab's commentary on the chmash Maayan Beis Hasho'eva which will at times focus on the haftorah independently.

Meshech Chochma, also Hebrew, will at times have insights into the haftorah as well.